# C# Test if there is already something drawn where I am going to draw

Tags: c#, drawing

I am trying to make a test to see if I have already drawn something where I am going to draw.

My drawing code:

```
Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
// Want my test to be here here
g.FillEllipse(brush, playerX-3, playerY-3, 6, 6);

g.Dispose();
```

Comment: Never call `CreateGraphics()`.  You need to handle the `Paint` event.

Comment: You should have a list of the things that you have on the screen, these things should also have a BoundsRect that you should check instead.

Comment: Problem is, that im creating many circles that create a line, would it require a lot to see if hundereds of circles/rectangles intersect ?

Answer (score 0):

Realistically you cannot do this the way you think you can.  When you draw a shape you already know where it's going.  You know the rectangle you're telling it to draw at.

You have to keep track of things you've drawn and where, then you can check against this list when you want to see where things are.

You absolutely need to do this no matter what because in reality you need to be painting in the `OnPaint` method or the `Paint` event and you should write within those methods the code to redraw the entire scene.

Comment: Isn't there a way to test if the alpha=0 on player(X,Y) in the panel graphics?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190152/disappearances-of-shapes-on-windows-forms).  The way it needs to work is that you keep track of the positions of each player and you keep track of their size.  The drawing is separate from the logic.  If you want to know if a player is at x,y position you would check the bounds of each player based on their location and size and see whether that rectangle contains the point requested using a function like `Rectangle.Contains(point)`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the painting or the graphics.  Your application must have logic that defines the state of the objects.  Your paint method simply enumerates through your state objects and draws them to the screen.

Comment: hmm, here comes the problem then: Im drawing MANY circles in a row (they shape a thick line)... I want to see when two lines intersect, or if one intersect with itself..

Comment: Doesn't matter if you have 10 or 1000, you can store everything you need to know in a List of objects.  Create a class or struct to represent each object and then paint them in a for/foreach loop.